# Wygwam if conditional

Tags: wygwam, ifelse

Basically i want to know if its possible for expression engines if tag to check if a wygwam field contains images.

I know its possible to pull through just images like so:

```
    {my_wygwam_field images_only="yes"}
      (code for images)
    {/wygwam_field}
```

but what if i want to check whether that tag returns any results. I tried

```
{if my_wygwam_field images_only="yes"}
    {my_wygwam_field images_only="yes"}
       (image code)
    {/wygwam_field}
{/if}
```

but it didn't seem to work. Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to vary your syntax slightly:

```
{if '{my_wygwam_field images_only="yes"}'}
    {my_wygwam_field images_only="yes"}
       (image code)
    {/wygwam_field}
{/if}
```

This way you're actually telling EE to parse that first tag (inside the conditional statement) - you need to do it this way because it's a tag pair requiring a parameter,so simple conditional checking won't work.